# Regex to limit repeating digits

Tags: javascript, regex, grails

I have a regex in a grails configuration that limits the repeating digits:

```
password.regex = /^(?!.*([0-9])\1{2,})/
```

this works fine when I test this in https://regex101.com/. But it doesn't work on the JS code we have because it modifies the regex to:

```
var passRegex = /(${ConfigurationHolder.config.password.regex})/;
```

so the result is like this instead:

```
/(^(?!.*([0-9])\1{2,}))/
```

Unfortunately, I can't change the js code so I will just rely on the modification of the config. Can someone help me modify this regex

```
/(^(?!.*([0-9])\1{2,}))/
```

so that it will work as expected without removing the first pair of open and close parenthesis.

Comment: Those outer parentheses do not do any harm.

Comment: Hi, but when I test this regex /(^(?!.*([0-9])\1{2,}))/ in regex101.com it doesnt work as expected in contrast with  /^(?!.*([0-9])\1{2,})/

Comment: Ah, I see, the backreference. So, just replace `\1` with `\2`. Try `password.regex = /^(?!.*([0-9])\2{2,})/`. So, you cannot change `var passRegex = /(${ConfigurationHolder.config.password.regex})/;` to `var passRegex = /${ConfigurationHolder.config.password.regex}/;`, can you?

Comment: Yes. I don't have control with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A logical solution would be to remove the outer parentheses from the code you have, like `var passRegex = /${ConfigurationHolder.config.password.regex}/;`.

If it is not an option, just replace `\1` with `\2` as the group with the digit to check against gets shifted and acquires a new ID = 2, `password.regex = /^(?!.*([0-9])\2{2,})/`.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain why it gets "shifted"?

Comment: I have no idea what your system does internally to the regex you defined. The main point is that backreferences point to the text captured with a specific capturing group. The groups are numbered from left to right, beginning with 1. So, your outer parentheses form Group 1, and the parentheses around `[0-9]` form Group 2. You need to reference Group 2, so, `\1` must be changed to `\2`.